# Please give me a 'kick-start' to build an app to log into a web site

Tags: android

Never built an app before.
Downloaded & installed SDK & Eclipse.

For my 'learning experience' I would like to build an app for my Galaxy S II (4.0.4) that will take me to a web site and then log me in, eg: my Gmail Account or my Voip.ms Account

Can someone point me to a tutorial or suggest how I should start such an app?

Is this too complicated to begin with?

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I think this is way too complicated to start as a learner. You may end up spending a lot more time in debugging some code which does not work because of some silly stuff rather than "learning" how to code Android.

I started with a simple app that has few screens, stores some info in local SQLite DB and sends some across to an remote SQL Server over internet. I managed to complete this in 2 weeks and got quite a good hold on Android basics. Now I am working on a much complex app and am not getting stuck in fundamental issues.

Answer (score 1):

[Developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/index.html) offers some good app examples and tutorials and is the first go-to location when you want to see how to do something Android-related.
As for what you want to do, it will really depend on the website. Going to the website in question, searching for a developer section is the way to go.
There they will explain which API they offer to devs.  OAuth + REST are widely adopted  but there is no universal solution, it really depends on the website.
A final note : embedding a webpage in an Android app is a very bad idea from an user-experience perspective, Using an API to offer a native app will always result in a better experience.

Comment: Thank you. I have the API code from the site to do what I want, I think. Now, could you point me to a tutorial on how to get started using this API information to build an app? Thanks, Rob.

Comment: @user1593640, Do you wish a tutorial like the following ?http://wowjava.wordpress.com/2011/01/16/login-application-for-android/

Comment: @user1593640, for the API, as you said, only the site that offers it can help you. There are probably some elements that are pretty common in this API (OAuth for example is a popular way to do authentification) but it is very likely that some parts of it are unique.

Comment: @user1593640, I would also advise you to have a look at the sample projects that the Android SDK allows you to create in Eclipse.
They cover many common apps, like a gallery or a mediaplayer with clean code (but not perfect).
The official site will provide you with the rest of the instructions you need. If you are not just new to Android, but also to development, a book like "Professional Android 4 Application Development" by Reto Meier is also a good source of knowledge (& since he is an Android dev advocate at Google, he knows what he is talking about.

Comment: Thanks to all. :) Bought "Professional Android 4 Application Development" by Reto Meier plus 'Beginning Android 4 Application Development' by Wei-Meng Lee.